# S3 CORS is not allowing origin for two domains

Tags: amazon-s3, cors

I have an S3 bucket where I would like to allow 2 domains to access the resources:

1. `http://asubdomain.mysite.com`
2. `http://localhost:3000`

Here is the CORS rule:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://asubdomain.mysite.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Yet when I try to access the resources on a page, I get this error... occasionally. Any ideas?

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_awesome_bucket/myfile.txt. 
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:3000' that is not equal to the supplied origin. 
Origin 'http://asubdomain.mysite.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: I think it may be due to the fact that I load the same resource twice on some page requests, just from different 'domains'. In the network tab, the resource says 304 - implying it was gotten elsewhere. In that case it may still be using the same header from the previous domain's request. interesting...

Comment: It is possible due to caching the request. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=378304#